# Having a Heroku LoadError

Tags: ruby, bash, deployment, heroku, web

I'm trying to go through a Heroku tutorial, and when I try to upload a public key here's what happens.

```
$ heroku keys:add

C:\dev\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- /cygdrive/c/dev/Ruby19
3/bin/heroku (LoadError)
```

I confirmed that there is definitely a heroku file in the bin directory, it's just not being picked up. Any ideas?

Here's the tutorial.

http://www.packtpub.com/article/building-tiny-web-applications-in-ruby-using-sinatra

Answer (score 1):

Do the following first:

```
   gem install heroku
```

than you can go for

```
   heroku keys:add
```